# How to automate user actions?

Tags: keyboard, apk, tasker, automation, touchscreen

I've seen a few questions similar to this before, but they all seem to be concerned with performing tasks in apps rather than actually simulating user action (e.g. swipes, taps, keypresses, etc.) in a similar manner to how AHK would work on Windows. I've seen a few solutions on the web calling for things like SL4A, but I can't find a clear explanation as to how I would go about fully automating an Android device.

Basically, what I want to do is open an app and activate a script (or something to the effect of a script, maybe an APK?) that will click on buttons and swipe up and down in a predetermined pattern (again, think AHK for Windows). Is something like this possible?

Comment: With Tasker and Autoinput app, yes.

Comment: There's lots of automation apps with such capabilities, like Automate: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate